# How do I use both, :start-after: and :lines:, with literalinclude?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx’s `literalinclude` with a code example and want to use both `start-after` and `lines`. However, all I am getting is an empty line. Is this a bug? If not, how do I it correctly?

#### Minimal non-working example

- `index.rst`, the main documentation file:

  ```
  Behold this example code:

  .. literalinclude:: example.py
      :start-after: blobfish
      :lines: 1
  ```
- `example.py`, the example to be included:

  ```
  # blobfish
  this = line is an_example
  this = line is another_example
  ```
- `conf.py`, because Sphinx needs one:

  ```
  source_suffix = '.rst'
  master_doc = 'index'
  ```

I compile by calling `sphinx-build . out` in the folder containing the above files. There is no error message.

In the output, I want to see the introductory sentence followed by `this = line is an_example`. However, instead of the latter I only get an empty line. If I change `:lines:` to `:emphasize-lines:`, everything is working as expected: The line in question is highlighted and the other line is printed additionally.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem and am pretty sure Sphinx does not support combining these two options. I suggest you create an issue here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues

Comment: @Timotheus.Kampik: That was what I was intending to do. [Here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3412) we go.